# Why does filter() have different type requirements on parallel iterators?

Tags: rust, rayon

I'm trying to understand why Rayon's `filter()` function won't work without needing to specify the right type, whereas `filter()` will work correctly if I'm not using a parallel iterator.  Here's my code:

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn is_even(n: i64) -> bool {
    n % 2 == 0
}

fn main() {
    let v: Vec<_> = (1..300_000_000)
        .into_par_iter()  //  works correctly without this line, but not parallel
        .filter(|&x| is_even(x))
        .collect();
}
```

And here are the error messages:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<rayon::range::Iter<i32> as rayon::iter::ParallelIterator>::Item == i64`
  --> src/main.rs:11:10
   |
11 |         .filter(|&x| is_even(x))
   |          ^^^^^^ expected `i32`, found `i64`

error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<rayon::range::Iter<i32> as rayon::iter::ParallelIterator>::Item == i64`
  --> src/main.rs:12:10
   |
12 |         .collect();
   |          ^^^^^^^ expected `i32`, found `i64`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `rayon::iter::ParallelIterator` for `rayon::iter::Filter<rayon::range::Iter<i32>, [closure@src/main.rs:11:17: 11:32]>`
```

Why does `filter()` only work without specifying the kind of integer if I'm not using `into_par_iter()`?  (I know I can fix it by labeling the range as i64, but not why it would be necessary)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Update:*** *This type inference issue has been [fixed](https://github.com/rayon-rs/rayon/pull/834) in rayon 1.5.1*

---

Why indeed... Digging into it, this is due to the way rayon determines if a `Range` implements `IntoParallelIterator`.

```
impl<T> IntoParallelIterator for Range<T> where Iter<T>: ParallelIterator { ... }

struct Iter<T> {
    range: Range<T>,
}

impl ParallelIterator for Iter<u8> { type Item = u8; }
impl ParallelIterator for Iter<u16> { type Item = u16; }
impl ParallelIterator for Iter<u32> { type Item = u32; }
impl ParallelIterator for Iter<u64> { type Item = u64; }
impl ParallelIterator for Iter<i8> { type Item = i8; }
impl ParallelIterator for Iter<i16> { type Item = i16; }
impl ParallelIterator for Iter<i32> { type Item = i32; }
impl ParallelIterator for Iter<i64> { type Item = i64; }
// etc
```

The compiler is trying to see if `(1..300_000_000).into_par_iter()` is even legal and because `ParallelIterator` is implemented for the `Iter<T>` types separately, its forced to deduce *now* what `T` is before it proceeds.

See the non-working reconstruction on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=878add570de6759df7ed3b1ddda7af78).

If instead they did something like:

```
impl<T> ParallelIterator for Iter<T> where T: SomeIntegerType + Send {
    type Item = T;
}

trait SomeIntegerType {}
impl SomeIntegerType for u8 {}
impl SomeIntegerType for u16 {}
impl SomeIntegerType for u32 {}
impl SomeIntegerType for u64 {}
impl SomeIntegerType for i8 {}
impl SomeIntegerType for i16 {}
impl SomeIntegerType for i32 {}
impl SomeIntegerType for i64 {}
// etc
```

The compiler can see that `Iter` *does* implement `ParallelIterator` as long as `T` implements `SomeIntegerType`, but it doesn't have to deduce the type *now*, it can wait until later.

See my working reconstruction on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1d9f14b5aedfefdbec6f138079833bc7).

Comment: Certainly can't hurt opening an issue to ask about it.

Comment: I opened an [issue](https://github.com/rayon-rs/rayon/issues/833) for it.